# Add entry to a dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++

So I've just learned about pointers. I wrote a code to initiate a list and copy the elements of list to new_list and add new elements to new_list. However, when I run my code, my compiler says that the add_entry in main() and the function are not a match. Plus the line where I initialize number_list, it says "excess elements in scalar initializer". Can you please check for me where am I getting wrong at? I'm not allowed to use vectors btw. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int T;

T* add_entry(T* list, const T& new_entry,int& size);


void print_list(T* list, int size);

int main() {
    T* number_list = new T[3];
    number_list = {1,2,3};
    number_list = add_entry(number_list, 3, 3);
    print_list(number_list, 4);

}

T* add_entry(T* list, const T& new_entry,int& size) {
    T* new_list;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        new_list[i] = list[i];
    }

    new_list[size] = new_entry;

    delete[] list;

    return new_list;

}

void print_list(T* list, int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << list[i] << endl;
}
```

## edit: the capacity parameter is a part of something else in this code, which I have deleted for demonstration since it's not good to ask too much on this forum. My code doesn't run still.

Comment: Dynamic array is spelled [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in C++.

Comment: We're not allowed to use vectors

Comment: Not allowed to use vectors? I really hope your professor didn't say "Use a dynamic array, no vectors."

Comment: How many arguments is add_entry supposed to have?, seems to change from declaration to definistion

Comment: We haven't learned about vectors yet, just dynamic arrays

Comment: Well, hopefully next sentence of the professor is: "See how complex all this matter is? There's an easy way to get around: `std::vector`." and that's really the next thing you learn - and smart pointers!

Comment: You cannot assign initialiser lists to arrays (`number_list = {1, 2, 3};`), either assign each element separately (`NL[0] = 1; NL[1] = 2; NL[2] = 3;`) or use the initialiser list right at creation (`T* NL = new T[3] { 1, 2, 3 };`).

Comment: Maybe make `size` param of add_entry a `const int&` instead of just `int&`? I try compiling your program and gcc barfs on `invalid initialization of nonconst reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'` at the call to add_entry with an arrow pointing at the second numeral '3'.

Comment: @PemiNguyen Please post a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem(s). Otherwise it is hard to help you out.

Comment: @Aconcagua oh, right. I guess it doesn't make much sense to take reference to a literal since it cannot be changed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Declaration and definition of `add_entry()` do indeed not match. The former is

```
T* add_entry(T* list, const T& new_entry,int& size);
```

while the latter is

```
T* add_entry(T* list, const T& new_entry,int& size, int& capacity)
```

As you seem to not use `capacity` inside the function, you should remove it from the parameter list.

Comment: Sorry I edited your comment. I'm new here and accidentally made  a wrong edit

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot wrong with this code, but to answer your question of compiler error, you didn't declare `int& capacity` in declaration,
`T* add_entry(T* list, const T& new_entry,int& size);`
 but mentioned it in function implementation. 
So it's a mismatch in number of parameters passed from `main` and arguments received in 
`T* add_entry(T* list, const T& new_entry,int& size, int& capacity)`

Comment: @PemiNguyen Now, can you explain why are you receiving `new_entry` and `size` by address? `&` receives  by address, you want the value (I believe). Try removing the `&` sign, only use it when you want to receive a pointer or address of some variable.

Comment: Also, I didn't really went through your code's logic, but you can't add more values in your dynamic array than the size it's declared for. You will have to use `linked list` or `vector`

Comment: @saadi `T* list` is an address. `int& size` is a reference.While unnecessary for `size`, it's certainly not problematic.

Comment: @sadii Can you demonstrate that? I can't use more complex data structures as we haven't learned about them yet!

Comment: @sadii My professor's prototype code has that part. I think that's not necessary but he want it that way so. Of course you can't add any element to a dynamic array. What I did was to create a new one and copy all the elements from the old one and add the new element to the last position

Comment: @PemiNguyen I suspect `size` is a reference because you are supposed to increment that value in the `add_entry` function.

Comment: @john: Oh yeah, I forgot. Size is a reference to the old list. and we keep updating that one

Comment: `size` is either `const int&` or `int&&` since a literal is passed to the function call.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I think the prototype has been designed by the professor (i.e. it can't be changed) and the intent is to pass a variable not a literal. The OP just wrote some test code which was incorrect (as he admits a couple of comments above).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is here

```
T* add_entry(T* list, const T& new_entry,int& size) {
    T* new_list;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        new_list[i] = list[i];
    }
    new_list[size] = new_entry;
    delete[] list;
    return new_list;
}
```

You haven't allocated any memory for `new_list` so you are dereferencing a garbage pointer. Not good, and likely to make your program crash. It should be

```
T* add_entry(T* list, const T& new_entry,int& size) {
    T* new_list = new T[size+1];
    ...
```

Also I suspect you are meant to increment the size inside this function (otherwise why would `size` be a reference) so the full function should look something like this

```
T* add_entry(T* list, const T& new_entry,int& size) {
    T* new_list = new T[size+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        new_list[i] = list[i];
    }
    new_list[size] = new_entry;
    delete[] list;
    ++size;
    return new_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains multiple errors:

- You have to pass `size` as const ref (const int&) or as r-value ref (int&&) since you want to pass literals to the function
- `size` should be unsigned
- A initializer list can only be used in contruction not later (`T* number_list = new T[3] {1,2,3};`)
- You have to allocate memory for `new_list` in `add_entry` (`T* new_list = new T[size + 1];`)

If the function signature is given by your professor and you can't change it you have to call the function `add_entry` with a variable `size`:

```
T* number_list = new T[3] {1,2,3};
int size = 3;
number_list = add_entry(number_list, 3, size);
print_list(number_list, size);
```

and you have to increment the size in `add_entry`